# Python regular expression not raising exception inside header.py

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

my client looks like this->

```
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
b = MIMEMultipart()
b['a'] = "Hello"
b['b'] = "--\nhttp://www.stallergenes.com/images/STAL_mail.png"
b.as_string()
```

This calls a function _write_headers in generator.py

This generator.py calls encode method in header.py

encode function inside header.py looks like this ->

```
def encode(self, splitchars=';, \t', maxlinelen=None, linesep='\n'):
    _embedded_header = re.compile(r'\n[^ \t]+:')
    print 'value in header.py is -> %s, %s, %s' %(value, type(value), _embeded_header.pattern, _embeded_header.search(value))
    if _embedded_header.search(value):
        raise HeaderParseError("header value appears to contain "
            "an embedded header: {!r}".format(value))
    return value
```

In python2.7, this is my `header.py` file inside docker container.

Value of print statement in header.py-> --\nhttp://www.stallergenes.com/images/STAL_mail.png, \n[^ \t]+:, None

So Basically, it should have been matched. why it is not getting matched against this regex?

Comment: If the output of `print` is `--\nhttp://www.stallergenes.com/images/STAL_mail.png`, then you do _not_ have a line break in the `value`. Otherwise, `'\n'` would be displayed as a line break. Apparently your `'\n'` is actually a `'\\n'`.

Comment: But why it is not breaking? it is also working fine for inputs like   "Cecilia Alarcon 12:01 PM:\n(y):D",    "Failed monitors include:\nFreeWheel: 2018-03-25",    "Anoka Stake Center\n6:30 & 7:30pmCT"

Answer (score -1):

`\n` matches a new line. I don't think that this was your purpose. If you escape it by adding a `\` it should work-

```
\\n[^ \t]+:
```

Comment: OP has a newline in `"--\nhttp://www.stallergenes.com/images/STAL_mail.png"`, it is not a sequence of ``\`` and `n` chars.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  What should I change? is this because of some raw string input?   
I tried with another input value in header.py is -> BUENAS TARDES.\nLES MANDO LOS REPORTES DE JL\nNOTA: SIN PAROS, <type 'str'>, None
searching --- -1


Code in header.py is something like this...
        print 'value in header.py is -> %s, %s, %s' %(value, type(value), _embeded_header.search(value))
        print 'searching --- %s' %(value.find('\n'))

Comment: @KartikThakurela Sorry, I cannot repro that.